# Does including unused headers have any impact on code?

Tags: c, unix, header-files

Let's say I have a C program which only uses functions from `stdio.h`.

Now, if I include unwanted headers like `stdlib.h`, `errno.h`, etc. and compile the program, then will these unwanted headers have an impact on code segment?

I say "unwanted headers" because the program does not use functions declared in these headers.

Comment: Headers don't load code into the program, they mostly just declare functions and structures. Code is loaded by linking with specific libraries.

Comment: It might take longer to compile; but on modern machines, the difference is likely too slight to notice.

Answer (score 2):

No, your program only pulls in code that it references to. Including a header you don't use will be optimized out of the final code.

I should clarify, "Including a header you don't use will not result in 'extra waste' in the final product." No code is optimized out because no code is actually generated(since it's not referenced).

Answer (score 1):

Head files are used for compiler, if there are "unused head files", compile time will be low when the project is small.

But for a big project, it should be well handled. And you know "Simple is Beauty!"

And it's nothing to do with final binary product.